# System T, System F and arithmetical hierarchy

Tags: lo.logic

I refer to [Proof and Types](http://www.paultaylor.eu/stable/prot.pdf) by Jean-Yves Girard for the definition of System T (pag. 46) and System F (pag. 81).
In this treatise there are two base types, i. e. $\text{Int}$ (natural numbers) and $\text{Bool}$ (booleans), so I suppose that the type $\text{Int} \rightarrow \text{Bool}$ can be seen as **set of natural numbers**. This gives me a curiosity: what is the position of the sets of System T in the arithmetical hierarchy? and about the sets of System F?
I searched in the literature, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: If $f \colon \mathrm{Int} \to \mathrm{Bool}$, then we can also of course get the complement of $f$ by negating, and since System T and F are strongly normalizing, this implies the set corresponding to $f$ is computable, so in $\Delta^0_1$.

Comment: @IzaakMeckler not *provably* in $\Delta^0_1$, though, from PA's point of view...

Comment: @cody: Hmph? For each particular $f$ there is a proof in $PA$ of the fact that $f$ characterizes a $\Delta_1^0$-predicate. I don't think anyone here suggested that we should understand Izaak's comment as saying "$\mathrm{PA} \vdash \lceil \forall f . f^{-1}(0) \in \Delta_1^0 \rceil$". That's an unusual amount of internalization.

Comment: I thought that in System T, functions and functionals were required to be primitive recursive, so Int->Bool would just be the relevant countable subset of $2^\omega$, not the whole set.

Comment: @AndrejBauer You're correct, I'm over-internalizing. Any *externally* decidable set is $\Delta^0_1$. Seems a little weird though.

Comment: @none: The Ackermann function is definable in System T but is not primitive recursive. Note that System T allows definitions of functions $\mathbb{N} \to A$ for *any* type $A$ (even a function type), whereas ordinary primitive recursion only works for $\mathbb{N}^k \to \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, thank you Izaak.

So $\Delta_0^0 \subsetneq T$ and $\Delta_0^0 \subsetneq F$ because in $T$ and in $F$ there are Sudan function, Ackermann function and so on; but $T \subsetneq \Delta_1^0$ and $F \subsetneq \Delta_1^0$ because all the functions in $T$ (or in $F$) are computable and total and by diagonalization it is possible to build a function total, computable, not in $T$ (or in $F$).

Only now I realize how much $\Delta_1^0$ is not constructive.